# How can I concatenate a string and a number in Python?

Tags: python

I was trying to concatenate a string and a number in Python. It gave me an error when I tried this:

```
"abc" + 9
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    "abc" + 9
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Why am I not able to do this?

How *can* I concatenate a string and a number in Python?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Python is [strongly typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing). There are no implicit type conversions.

You have to do one of these:

```
"asd%d" % 9
"asd" + str(9)
```

Comment: What about a variable with a string object assigned to it?

Comment: Another option is  g = 9   f’asd{g}’

Comment: TIL that Python is strongly typed without most of the benefits that strong typing offers, but with all the hindrances. Hating Python even more now.

Answer (score 29):

If it worked the way you expected it to (resulting in `"abc9"`), what would `"9" + 9` deliver? `18` or `"99"`?

To remove this ambiguity, you are required to make explicit what you want to convert in this case:

```
"abc" + str(9)
```

Answer (score 15):

Since [Python is a strongly typed](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language) language, concatenating a string and an integer, as you may do in Perl, makes no sense, *because there's no defined way to "add" strings and numbers to each other.*

> Explicit is better than implicit.

...says ["The Zen of Python"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), so you have to concatenate two string objects. You can do this by creating a string from the integer using the built-in [`str()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str) function:

```
>>> "abc" + str(9)
'abc9'
```

Alternatively, use [Python's string formatting operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
>>> 'abc%d' % 9
'abc9'
```

Perhaps better still, use [`str.format()`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> 'abc{0}'.format(9)
'abc9'
```

The Zen also says:

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Which is why I've given three options.

Answer (score 8):

Either something like this:

```
"abc" + str(9)
```

or

```
"abs{0}".format(9)
```

or

```
"abs%d" % (9,)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the int into a string:

```
"abc" + str(9)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to convert the int into a string.

```
# This program calculates a workers gross pay

hours = float(raw_input("Enter hours worked: \n"))

rate = float(raw_input("Enter your hourly rate of pay: \n"))

gross = hours * rate

print "Your gross pay for working " +str(hours)+ " at a rate of " + str(rate) + " hourly is $"  + str(gross)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this:

```
"abc%s" % 9
#or
"abc" + str(9)
```