# How to write the function in a more pythonic way?

Tags: python

I got the following function written in python.

```
def get_campaign_id(campaigns, campaign_name):
  for c in campaigns:
    if c['name'] == campaign_name:
      return c['id']
  return None
```

campaigns is a list of dicts, e.g.

```
campaigns = [{'name': 'campaign1', 'id': 91203}]
```

and campaign_name is a `str`

Comment: This should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981717/pythonic-way-to-combine-for-loop-and-if-statement

Comment: could be done in one line: `return c['id'] for c in campaigns if c['name'] == campaign_name else None`

Comment: There is absolutely nothing un-pythonic about your method. It is explicit, clear and easy to understand.  Remember that "one liner" doesn't mean "pythonic".

Comment: @agconti That returns an iterator, not the id of the first matching dictionary.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid meh .. looping through the whole list to find one id over and over again is not very efficient ... (especially if you have to do it multiple times)

Comment: Perhaps the only improvement you can do is sort the list by the campaign names, but other than that I think its great. @JoranBeasley given the constraints of the system (list of dicts), there is very little that can be done other than that. Your answer that creates another structure may not be possible if his method is being called by another function (so he cannot create it "once").

Comment: meh a list is not the proper data structure for this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mapping =dict([c["name"],c["id"]) for c in campaigns]) #save this ... dont recreate it all the time
print mapping[campaign_name] # get the id by campaign name
```

is probably a better way to do it ...

Comment: Yes... but it uses O(n) memory instead of O(1).

Comment: what makes you think a list is O(1) memory useage? ... Im pretty sure most of the time the whole list is in memory ...

Comment: When you speak of memory asymptotic complexity you generally include only *extra* memory used. In other words: your solution doubles the amount of memory required. `dict` uses quite a bit more memory than a list of the same size with the same contents, so your code uses strictly more than twice the memory of the original.

Comment: I doubt it ... since its a list of dicts then that implies it would use `dict memory * list size` I would be curious to see an analysis though (tbh Im not sure how to examine memory footprint)  (Im also assuming you could discard the original list)

Comment: Where does the multiplication comes from? My O(n) refers to the fact that the `dict` pointed to by `mapping` has a size that is proportional to the length of the original list (`campaigns`). Even if you can disregard the original list, in order to built the dict they must "live together" for some time.  The original solution doesn't even allocate any new object.

Comment: I see... yes if both objects are living together in the program space the it is 2x as much memory (although thats likely not an issue with modern hardware) I was referring to the original list being `[dict1,dict2,dict3,...]` thus size is `[overhead_of_dict+content,overhead_of_dict+content,...]` where as my solution only has one overhead of `dict + content`  (ie the mapping datastructure is likely a smaller memory footprint than the campaigns list datastructure), I thought you were saying mapping would have a larger overhead than the list