# Accessing specific variable in Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading in Python a Matlab `mat` file, which contains three arrays: `tom, dick and harry`. In Python, I use a `for` loop which does operations on this array list. Following is the demo-code:

```
import scipy.io as sio
mat_contents = sio.loadmat('names.mat') # with arrays tom, dick and harry
varlist = ['tom', 'dick', 'harry']
for w in varlist:
    cl = mat_contents[w]
    # some more operations in the loop
```

Now that I have to debug and do not want to access all the three `varlist` for the `for` loop. How to run the for loop only for `harry`? I know `varlist[2]` gets me `harry`, but I could not succeed getting it alone for the `for` loop.

Comment: you mean `varlist[2:3]`?

Comment: put `if w == "harry": do operations...` inside for loop. Please specify the input and desired output if it doesn't help, it will help to understand the question better.

Comment: @jyotish: Thanks. I could combine the `for` and `if` using the [generator expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6981771/1977614) and make it work. I feel this is still a way around. I hope that someone would provide a direct answer for the question.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment: now controllable with a single variable:

```
import scipy.io as sio
mat_contents = sio.loadmat('names.mat') # with arrays tom, dick and harry
varlist = ['tom', 'dick', 'harry']

# set it to -1 to disable it and use all arrays
debug_index = -1

# or set it to an index to only use that array
debug_index = 1

for w in [varlist[debug_index]] if debug_index + 1 else varlist:
    cl = mat_contents[w]
    # some more operations in the loop
```

Comment: This serves the purpose. But it is not what I am looking for. Lets say I would like to debug for `tom`. Can it be made as simple as changing the index and not typing the names for each?