# What does 'for .. in .. if ... not' mean?

Tags: python

There's a function I don't get:

```
def group_regularization(v):
    const_coeff = lambda W: tf.sqrt(tf.cast(W.get_shape().as_list()[1], tf.float32))
    return tf.reduce_sum([tf.multiply(const_coeff(W), l21_norm(W)) for W in v if 'bias' not in W.name])
```

What does the last line mean?

At first I thought it was "apply the function to `W` except the ones with name `bias`", but I'm not sure.

Comment: [Pythonic way to combine FOR loop and IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6981717/6521116)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with a condition. It has nothing to do with Tensorflow, it's just basic Python.

Conditional list comprehensions take the form

```
[<expression> for <name> in <list> if <condition>]
```

This iterates over all elements in `<list>` for which `<condition>` is true, assigning each to `<name>` in turn, evaluating `<expression>`, and making a new list of the results. It's equivalent to

```
new_list = []
for <name> in <list>:
    if <condition>:
        new_list.append(<expression>)
```

except that the list comprehension is cleaner code and possibly a bit faster to run.

Answer (score 1):

It represents list comprehension expanded as the following:

```
out_list = []
def group_regularization(v):
    ...
    for W in v:
        if 'bias' not in W.name:
            out_list.append(tf.multiply(const_coeff(W), l21_norm(W)))
    tf.reduce_sum(out_list)
```

It is iterating through each item in `v` passed as **list** in `group_regularization`

Then, checking if string 'bias' is not in W.name

and then, doing(whatever) operation for tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down, it's convention in python:

```
#Step 1:
for W in v 
# Will foreach loop W for every item in v

#Step 2:
if 'bias' not in W.name #
# in loop, check if 'bias' was an element of list W.name, if yes, dont do anything with that, if not, do next

#Step 3:
const_coeff(W), l21_norm(W))
# calculate these 2

#Step 4:
tf.multiply(const_coeff(W), l21_norm(W)))
# put those calculated in step 3 into tf.multiply

#Step 5:
[tf.multiply(....)]
# put everything in a list (since you have a loop at step 1)

#Step 6:
tf.reduct_sum([...])
# calculate reduce_sum

#Step 7:
return ....
# pass that result out
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a **list comprehension with a condition**. List comprehensions can have multiple conditions.

The general format for a list comprehension with a `if` condition is this,

```
[<expression> for <value> in <iterable> if <condition>]
```

You can also have an `if..else` in the comprehension

```
[<expression> if <condition> else <expression> for <value> in <iterable> ]
```

**NOTE:** Your iterable can be `list,tuple,set,string,...etc`

To make things clear consider this simple example,

```
>>> v = [1,2,3,4]
>>> v
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Assume this is your `v` from your given code, also for understanding purposes let's say `Wname` is something similar to `W.name`

```
>>> Wname = [1,2]
>>> Wname
[1, 2]
```

Now suddenly you decide **I want a list x which has items from v but not in Wname**. Hmmm... How to do that? Take a look below.

```
>>> x = [W for W in v if W not in Wname]
>>> x
[3, 4]
```

Somewhat along these lines is what's happening in the code you mentioned above.