# How to make an IF inside a FOR loop work on a DataFrame? Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, dataframe

I am trying to select segments/ clauses of sentences, based on word pairs with which the segments should start. For example, I am interested in sentence segments that start with "what does" or "what is', etc.

To do this, I am looping over two DataFrames, using an `if statement` inside a `for loop` as shown below. The first DataFrame `df1['Sentence']` contains the sentences. The other `df2['First2']` contains the pairs of starting words. However, the function seems to loop *only* over the first word pair in the `for loop` - after the first item, it does not return to the for loop. My code seems to work when I would pass lists to it, but not when I pass DataFrames. I have tried the solutions mentioned in [Pythonic way to combine FOR loop and IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981717/pythonic-way-to-combine-for-loop-and-if-statement). But they do not work for my DataFrame. I would love to know how to solve this.

DataFrames:

```
   'Sentence'                                   'First2'     
0  If this is a string what does it say?      0  what does    
1  And this is a string, should it say more?  1  should it    
2  This is yet another string.                2
```

My code looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd    
a = df1['Sentence']
b = df2['First2'] 

#The function seems to loop over all r's but not over all b's:
def func(r): 
    for i in b:
        if i in r:
            # The following line selects the sentence segment that starts with 
            # the words in `First2`, up to the end of the sentence.
            q = r[r.index(i):] 
            return q
        else:
            return ''

df1['Clauses'] = a.apply(func)
```

This is the result:

```
what does it say?
```

This is correct but incomplete. The code seems to loop over all `r`'s but not over all `b`'s. How to get the desired result, as below?

```
what does it say?
should it say more?
```

Comment: Using `if i in r:` inside the `for i in b:` set `i` to on evalue then changes it to another - try different variable names?

Comment: You always return in the first iteration of the loop, either with `q` or the empty string. You never see the second element of `b`.

Comment: @doctorlove: But what I want to know if is if `i` is in both `b` AND `r` ... Would that work if I change `i` to for example `x`, in one of the statements?

Comment: @Evert: Yes, that seems right. But how to change that?

Comment: @Evert: Have corrected your point in the question.

Comment: As far as I can see, you still exit within the first iteration: the if-else statement returns on either branch, thus never letting the loop go to its next iteration.

Comment: @Evert: Yes, but what you point out is the key problem. I do not know how to solve that. What I meant with 'corrected your point' is that I have updated that the function  loops over all `r`'s but not all `b`'s (I had written that in correctly).

Comment: @Goyo: The contents of both DataFrames `df1['Sentence']` and `df2['First2']` is written at the top of my question. There are no other DataFrames.

Comment: @twhale To solve that do not return until the `for` loop is completed.

Comment: @Goyo I am relatively new to programming and understand what you say in principle. But can you show what to change in my code to implement your suggestion?

Comment: I have found the error in my code and posted the solution below. It implements your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm getting this right, but it looks like you want to store all the phrases from `'First2'` (in say a variable `s`), and have a column `'Clauses'` that is the remainder of the string after any match with any of the phrases contained in `s`.

There's probably a more efficient method, but a here's hacky way to do this with regular expressions:

```
# build the capturing string
s = '(' + '|'.join(df.First2[df.First2 != ''].values + '.*') + ')'
# use the pandas Series.str method to extract, and assign to new column
df['Clauses'] = df.Sentence.str.extract(s, expand = False)
```

Comment: I would like to have a column `Clauses` that contains the sentence segments that begin with the First2 words, all the way to the end of the sentence. The segment needs to include the First2 words also. I have updated the comments in the code to hopefully make this more clear.

Comment: I think what your answer does is select any sentence segment that contains the words in `First2`, leaving the words themselves out. But I want them in and also, I want the selection to be case sensitive. So if `First2` is in lowercase, only segments should be selected in which the words are lowercase.

Comment: Have you actually tried running the code in my answer?

Comment: Yes of course. But it did not give the desired result. I have posted the solution below. There was a mistake in my original code.

Answer (score 0):

This code answers my question:

```
import pandas as pd    
a = df1['Sentence']
b = df2['First2'] 

def func(r):
    for i in b:
        if i in r:
            q = r[r.index(i):]
            return q
    return ''

df['Segments'] = a.apply(func)
```

It was pointed out by Daming Lu here: [How to select sub-strings based on the presence of word pairs? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106176/how-to-select-sub-strings-based-on-the-presence-of-word-pairs-python) Hope this helps others.