# How to avoid converting an integer to string when concatenating

Tags: python

I know that in python, you can't simply do this:

```
number = 1
print "hello number " + number
```

you have to do this:

```
print "hello number " + str(number)
```

otherwise you'll get an error.

**My question is then**, being python such a compact language and this feature of automatic casting/converting from integer to string available in so many other languages, isn't there away to avoid having to use the `str()` function everytime? Some obscure import, or simply another way to do it?

**Edit:** When I say another way, I mean simpler more compact way to write it. So, I wouldn't really consider `format` and alternative for instance.

Thanks.

Comment: Not a duplicate.. I know how to concatenate the string. I am asking if there is a way to not having to do it that way.

Comment: I found a better duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use the more compact format

```
>>> print "one",1,"two",2
one 1 two 2
```

Or, in python 3,

```
>>> print("one",1,"two",2)
one 1 two 2
```

Notice however that both options will always introduce a space between each argument, which makes it unsuitable for more complex output formatting, where you should use some of the other solutions presented.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid `str()`:

```
print 'hello number {}'.format(number)
```

Anyway,

```
'abc' + 123
```

is equivalent to

```
'abc'.__add__(123)
```

and the `__add__` method of strings accepts only strings.

Just like

```
123 + 'abc'
```

is equivalent to

```
(123).__add__('abc')
```

and the `__add__` method of integers accept only numbers (int/float).

Comment: While this is the right way to go for more complex cases, wouldn't `print "hello number", number` work equally well here?

Comment: @DSM - yes, it would.

Comment: @DSM that's excatly the kind of answer I was looking for. Consider writing it as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use string formatting, [old](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

```
print "hello number %s" % number
```

or [new](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
print "hello number {}".format(number)
```

Comment: be aware that this calls str under the hood (I think at least) ... same with the other format string. just like "%d" will call int and %f will call float

Answer (score 1):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6981532/1167234) answer explains, this will not happen in Python because it is strongly typed. This means that Python will not convert types that you do not explicitly say to convert.