# String equivalent of +=

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Is there an equivalent of += for a string?

ie:

```
x = 1
while x <= 100:
    y = x
    if x % 3 == 0:
        y = 'Fizz'
    if x % 5 == 0:
        y += 'Buzz'
    if x % 7 == 0:
        y += 'Foo'
    if x % 11 == 0:
        y += 'Bar'
    print y
    x += 1
raw_input('Press enter to exit...')
```

This should return `a string and a second string` if the same rules as with numbers applied. Is it possible to do this? Because just doing that returns `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'`, even though `y` is a string to begin with, not an `int`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a `y` in your snippet...

Comment: Should work fine, check your assumptions.

Comment: The code snippet you show is okay. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you sure that `y` is not an integer?

Comment: You can not (obviously) join a `string` with a `integer` by doing `"some string" + 1`, but you can do `"some string" + str(1)` obviously. There's no other ways of doing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python String and Integer concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847386/python-string-and-integer-concatenation)

Comment: @lc thats because the error was from another piece of code, a fizzbuzz i was making. ill edit the op with all my code

Comment: Ahh, i see what i did. If the first if is skipped, then the second assumes that the first was true, thats where the error is.

Comment: In fact a single change of `y = x` to `y = str(x)` would avoid the error. You should use `+=` for `'Fizz'` as well!

Comment: "Even though `y` is a string to begin with, not an `int`" **This is not the case** (unless `x` is divisible by `3`). Voting to close as a typo. [Please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [track down such problems](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it using `isinstance()`

```
x = 1
while x <= 100:
    y = x
    if x % 3 == 0:
        y = 'Fizz'
    if x % 5 == 0:
        if isinstance(y, str):
            y += 'Buzz'
        else:
            y = 'Buzz'
    if x % 7 == 0:
        if isinstance(y, str):
            y += 'Foo'
        else:
            y = 'Foo'
    if x % 11 == 0:
        if isinstance(y, str):
            y += 'Bar'
        else:
           y = 'Bar'
    print y
    x += 1
raw_input('Press enter to exit...')
```

Please tell me if this particularly bad code (which I have a habit of writing).

Comment: @Torxed won't that mean that if the first `if` is skipped, `y` will be `xBuzz`?

Comment: @Torxed yep, tried that out just returns e.g `xFooBar` (where x is the number) instead for `FooBar`

Answer (score 3):

If you do this:
You are concatenating a string to string:

```
x = 'a string'
x += '6'
print x
```

If you do this:
You concatenate int to string so you get error:

```
x = 'a string'
x += 6
print x
```

error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

You have to make sure variable type before doing '+' operation; based on variable type, python can add or concatenate

Answer (score 1):

That would be `s1 += s2`:

```
>>> s1 = "a string"
>>> s1 += " and a second string"
>>> s1
'a string and a second string'
>>>
```

Unlike Perl, Python mostly refuses to perform implicit conversions (the numeric types being the principal exception). To concatenate the string representation of an integer `i` to a string `s`, you would have to write

```
s += str(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me for Python 2.7.4 and Python 3.0:

```
a='aaa'
a+='bbb'
print(a)
aaabbb
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but maybe you are looking for `operator`

```
operator.iadd(a, b)¶
operator.__iadd__(a, b)
a = iadd(a, b) is equivalent to a += b.
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html

```
x = 'a string'
x += ' and a second string'
print x

operator.iadd(x, ' and a third string')

print x
```

[How can I concatenate a string and a number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981495/how-can-i-concatenate-a-string-and-a-number-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 1
while x <= 100:
    y = str(x)
    if x % 3 == 0:
        y = 'Fizz'
    if x % 5 == 0:
        y += 'Buzz'
    if x % 7 == 0:
        y += 'Foo'
    if x % 11 == 0:
        y += 'Bar'
    print y
    x += 1
raw_input('Press enter to exit...')
```

It's quite simple.
You start off by defining `X` as an `integer`, then you increese it in a `while` loop.
At the very beginning of each iteration you define `y = x` which essentially tells python to set `y` into an integer.

Then depending on what `x modulus <nr>` you got, you add a `string` to the integer called `y` (yes, it is an integer as well).. This leads to an error because it's an illegal operation because of the way a `INT` and a `WORD` works, they're just different so you need to treat one of them prior to merging them into the same variable.

**How to debug your own code:** Try doing `print(type(x), type(y))` and you get the differences of the two variables.. Might help you wrap your head around this.

The solution is `y = str(x)`.

### So, no.. Y is NOT a string to begin with

Because you redefine `y` each iteration of your `while` loop.
`y = x` <-- Makes `Y` a int, because that's what `x` is :)

### Also, try using .format()

```
x = 1
while x <= 100:
    y = x
    if x % 3 == 0:
        y = '{0}Fizz'.format(x)
    if x % 5 == 0:
        y += '{0}Buzz'.format(x)
    if x % 7 == 0:
        y += '{0}Foo'.format(x)
    if x % 11 == 0:
        y += '{0}Bar'.format(x)
    print y
    x += 1
raw_input('Press enter to exit...')
```

Another personal observation is that if `x % 3 == 0` you replace `y = ...`, but in all other if-cases you append to `y`, why is this? I left it just the way you gave us the code but either do `elif` on the rest or `why not concade on all`if`'s`

Comment: ahh, yes. So is this better than the solution I came up with? (look down a few answers)

Comment: @mm865 Considering i changed 1 line of code, you doubled the code.. I'd say mine makes more sense? Altho all answers are good answers i personally think you should not mess with the code to much in order to fix an issue unless you gain more functionality out of it. So in this particular case, i think my code will be understood quicker and be more efficient considering i only added 5 characters of code on 1 line in order to achieve the same outcome? :) **Also**, in 100% of the cases, you will replace `Y` with for instance `Foo`, his expected result is `<nr> Foo`?