# Write multiple strings into a text file as a single line

Tags: python, text-files

I want to write something as one line such as:

```
Blah blah 123456 0.0000123
```

I used the below code:

```
value1 = 123456
value2 = 0.0000123
k = "Blah blah" + value1 +value2
File.write(k)
#outFile.write("Blah blah %s %s" % (value1 ,value2) )
```

The output is always:

```
Blah blah 123456
0.0000123
```

Comment: What happens if you [print](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) `k` to the terminal?

Comment: `k = "Blah blah" + value1 +value2` can't work if you don't convert the numbers to strings first.

Comment: str(value1).strip() + str(value2).strip() might work. please try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I concatenate a string and a number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981495/how-can-i-concatenate-a-string-and-a-number-in-python)

Comment: `k = "Blah blah {0} {1}".format(123456, 0.0000123)`

Comment: I did convert them to string

Comment: @NathanArthur It still prints it wrong ie., not the way I want

Comment: @be_good_do_good This works! str(value1).strip(). Thank you!

Comment: @Gigl posted as answer, if you find it helpful, please upvote

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible; the code in the OP would cause errors. Please read [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your integers to strings (see this answer : [Making a string out of a string and an integer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823211/making-a-string-out-of-a-string-and-an-integer-in-python) )

```
k = "Blah blah" + str(value1) + str(value2)
```

same thing with the %s formatters. The parameters should be str(variables), not just variables

Comment: I did convert both the values to string @Pac0

Comment: @Gigl in this case, you have to use `.strip()` additionaly, as you and others have pointed out. However, I'm curious about why you have a trailing newline. Which operating system do you use ?

Answer (score 1):

Integers when concatenated with strings have an assumed endline character afterwards. To remedy this problem, you can convert these ints to strings before concatenating all of them. You can do this with the str() function which is written about here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert them to strings and strip them to remove any tailing characters.

```
str(value1).strip() + str(value2).strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
>>> value1 = '123456'
>>> value2 = '0.000123'
>>> k = "Blah blah " + value1 + " " + value2
>>> print k
Blah blah 123456 0.000123
```

Do note the space after the second "blah", and the space between value1 and value2 in line 3.

You have to make sure you value1 and value2 are set as strings. You can also do it like this:

```
>>> value1 = 123456
>>> value2 = 0.000123
>>> str(value1)
>>> str(value2)
```

Comment: I tried this -  converted both values to string. It just becomes

    Blah blah 123456 \n
     <space> 0.0000123

Comment: Try doing this: `file_name = 'text_file.txt'
f = open(file_name, 'w')
value1 = '123456'
value2 = '0.0000123'
k = "Blah blah " + value1 + ' ' + value2
f.write(k)
f.close()`. I just tried it and it gave me the output you're looking for. Look through your code to see if you don't have a \n anywhere in your output.

Comment: Thanks! It worked with str(value).strip(), I can try with this too!